# how to check if div is empty and make disappear?

Tags: jquery

What i have is sometimes on ym page a div could be empty and it takes up empty space.
So i want to be able to hide it of make the width small if it is empty..

this is the html...

```
<div class="four columns">
        <div class="inner-column" style="height:500px;overflow: auto;">            
             <ul class="SubMenu">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

this is the jquery i am trying...

```
if ($('.four columns').is(":empty")) {
            $('.four').css('width','15px');
        }
```

whats should it be?

example:http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/yad9Q/6/

Comment: your selector is wrong. It should be `$('.four.columns')`

Comment: Maybe some more code or information about what you're trying to do might help. This code works if `.four.columns` has an original height of `< 15px`. The condition returns true if `.four.columns` is empty. Meaning no html or text.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/uzi002/yad9Q/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with checking `text()` for a length of zero or against an empty string is that it includes all tabs and spaces. So apply a `$.trim()` to the result ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/yad9Q/20/)):

```
$(function() {

    if ($.trim( $('.four.columns').text() ).length === 0) {
        $('.four.columns').hide();
    }

});​​​​​​
```

Also, in case you want to check all of the columns, use:

```
$(function() {

    /* check all columns */
    $('.columns').each(function(){
        if ($.trim( $(this).text() ).length === 0) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

});​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

The technique I typically use is to test the length of the text in the div:

```
if ($('.four.columns').text().length === 0) {
    $('.four').css('width', '15px');
}
```

Comment: The selector should be `.four.columns`.

Comment: I just copied it directly from the OP's example, but you are correct. Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
if ($('.four columns').text() === '') {
        $('.four colums').hide();
    }
```

or

```
if ($('.four columns').html() === '') {
        $('.four colums').hide();
    }
```

Comment: The selector should be `.four.columns`.

Comment: that makes it smaller even if there is links in submenu

Answer (score 0):

You can make the height 0 or hide it :

```
if($(".innerColumn").text() == ""){
   $(".innerColumn").css("height",0); or $(".innerColumn").hide()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you cant sparate classes with a space

```
<div class="four columns">
```

This are now 2 classes called "four" and "columns" so the class is not called four columns.

I should choose the lenght function to check if its empty.

```
if ( $('.columns .inner-column').html().length === 0 ){
  $(".columns .inner-column").hide()
}
```

The hide function hides the entire element. Its in the source code, but not visible for the client.

May I ask why you want to solve this problem client side? I think its smarter to check serverside if the content is empty, and then not generate the image.

Comment: on page load the menu on the left is created which has child pages, if there are no child pages then the left side is empty, but there is empty space there

Comment: also i tried the above and still doesnt work and yes i know there are two classes applied to that div

Comment: I think you want to check if the ul is empty. Its impotent that you select the right selector. __.inner-colum__ is not empty because there is a ul inside. The ul is empty so you want to check that one. This works: http://jsfiddle.net/yad9Q/19/

Comment: @S.Visser The demo you shared hides everything. There is also a `.twelve.columns` which is hidden because `.SubMenu` doesn't exist and thus has no html length.